# Google login integration with Angular 2 mobile app

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 2 and I'm trying to integrate the gmail login into my app. But while trying to connect getting below issue.

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>   The JavaScript origin in the request, http://localhost:8100, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/616153351200-4226q2vma5fnkm2l62ufc4i6rc5evrab.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=616153351200 to update the authorized JavaScript origins

Please kindly help me fix this issue.

Comment: You mean angular2? And what is *loing*?

Comment: yes, i am working angular 2. Somehow I have achieved this by Angular2 SocialLoginModule npm module, but it's not working in a mobile device. working perfectly in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Google Cloud Platform application APIs and Services from the side menu.

- Click on Credentials.
- Click on the client name that you have configured for OAuth.
- In the restriction section, fill in the required Authorized JavaScript Origins field.
- If you have any
  redirects to be handled then add them in the Authorized redirect URIs
  section.

Comment: I have achieved this by Angular2SocialLoginModule npm module, but it's not working in mobile device. working perfect in browser

Comment: It is very difficult to say without looking at the implementation, but is this localhost address hard coded some where? If yes localhost for mobile emulator is 10.0.2.2, maybe there is something that can be fixed in that regards!